# How to spawn on a squad member by clicking their name?

Tags: pc, battlefield-1

I remember in previous Battlefield games you'd be able to click on a squad member's name in your squad menu on the map rather than their little dot.  Sometimes it's kind of hard to click on their little dot especially if there are objectives, vehicles or other squad members nearby.

Has this changed? Is it bugged? Is there something on my end I need to do to enable it?

Comment: I thought you just can double-click the name and spawn to your squad mate.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm saying isn't working.  Clicking on their name doesn't work.  Any ideas why that would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be able to use your arrow keys to select a squad member.
For console members, the D-pad should serve this purpose as well.